# to remove single namespace for single element from soap response in java ,

Tags: java, xml, soapui

I'm trying to through an `FAULT EXCEPTION` in the `SOAP RESPONSE`. I am able to through Fault exception but I want one of the namespace for only 1 element to be removed in response . Right now The soap response looks like :

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" >
   <soap:Header>
      <ns2:TransactionID xmlns:"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/>VALUE</ns2:TransactionID>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive">
         <faultcode>the listen</faultcode>
         <faultstring>a batter/faultstring>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**What I want is :**

I  want to remove the `xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive"` or namespace for the only `soap:Fault` element and keep the other namespaces.

**I tried to use :**

```
soapElementName =  se.createName("Fault");
```

or

soapElementName =  se.createName("Fault", " " , " " );

```
SOAPElement faultElement = soapBody.addBodyElement(soapElementName);
```

But If I use the above code I am not even getting any response in soap ui as it is throwing an error , the only code with which its working or allowing is below :

```
soapElementName =  se.createName("Fault", "ns2",                     "http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive" );
```

Please suggest me a solution to remove a namespace from a single element or tag .

Comment: You really should consider improving the quality of your questions. Try avoiding all-caps and add `code` where appropriate.

Comment: , ninetainedo - please suggest a solution for the above problem . please let me know if u need more information.

Answer (score 0):

On your Wsdl schema definition use elementFormDefault as unqualified.

`elementFormDefault="unqualified"`.

If you specify element as qualified  we enforce namespace declaration to be used in documents validated with this schema.

Comment: , thank u for the reply arun , but i want to remove namespace for only one element , only one scenario and that scenario is when fault exception is thrown. please let me know if u know a solution for this .

Comment: My understing from your snippet is that you have Fault class schema definition in seperate file. If so, wrtie your Fault schema defintion with elementFormDefault="unqualified" and your soap definition with elementFormQualified-"qualified".

Comment: if this is not working out, create element as attribute and write attributeFormDefault="unqualified" in your schema definition